# react-native app not launching on simulator

Tags: react-native, ios-simulator, watchman

This is the first time im trying to run a react native app on ios simulator,but something went wrong ,build is succeeded but appp is not launching on simulator and some watchman error s are visible. [image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling watchman ?

Comment: @Madhavan.V Yes tried.But still same

Answer (score 1):

> 1.Open xcodeproj(awesomeApp/ios/awesomeApp.xcodeproj) in XCODE,And ensure that xcodeproj and the build directory have the required
>   permissions.
>
> 2.In xcode navigate to Window -> Devices and simulators ->simulators
>
> 3.Delete the simulator and add again
>
> 4.Press run/play button.